# How to view a directory or file with special characters in eshell?

Tags: emacs, eshell

I have a directory with `$` at the start of the directory name. How do I cd into it in eshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask, have you tried to put dir name into quotes? Sample eshell session:

```
~ $ mkdir '$testdir'
~ $ cd '$testdir'
~/$testdir $
```

Comment: Nice to know this. I usually put escape character on Bash. I tried on Bash and it works as well. Thanks. However, how do I do auto-completion with such directory?

Comment: @Amumu I'm pretty sure you're out of luck with auto-completion here (at least without intrusive configuration changes).